# Eclipse: Unable to save configuration file ".../org.eclipse.update/platform.xml.tmp"

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, configuration, launch

I am running Eclipse on two MAC OS X (10.9.4) machines. Both systems are running Kepler and both configurations should be identical. But when I launch the application under development on one system, I do get the error message

```
Unable to save configuration file ".../.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.../org.eclipse.update/platform.xml.tmp"
```

while the other system is behaving fine. It has nothing to do with access rights or disk space. The TMP file has a size of 0 bytes. If I remove any files or directories, they will be recreated except the *platform.xml*, *platform.xml.tmp* resp.

The behavior is reproduceable with the Luna release. But I think the error message is misleading. It suggests insuffient access rights or disk space. But it must be caused by a configuration error.

Does any one have an idea where to look?

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your Eclipse IDE and then delete this folder:

```
".../.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/<the_name_of_the_configuration_you_launch>/"
```

Start your Eclipse again and you're good to go.

Somehow PDE-build and the launcher conflicts. I don't know why exactly, but you can fix it with this delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Eclipse as an Administrator.  In Windows, Right click the exe file and then select "Run as Administrator".  If it starts successfully, check your Eclipse and Workspace folders' Security Permissions.